# TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `isAdmin.isAdmin` schematype definition is invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, webidl

The server is crashing because of the line
isAdmin: { isAdmin: boolean, default: false },

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably crashing because `isAdmin` is not valid field of mongoose schema, instead your schema declaration  schould looks like

```
new mongoose.Schema({
...// rest of your schema
isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false}
})
```

so simply replace
`isAdmin: boolean` with `type: Boolean`